# How can I get all TeX / LaTeX symbols?

Tags: symbols

I am currently writing the practical part of my bachelors thesis which will be about on-line recognition of handwritten mathematical symbols (and eventually also formuae).

One problem I currently have with this is that I need to have the symbols in my database. I basically need

- The latex code for the symbol (e.g. `A`, `$\alpha$`, `$\rightarrow$`, `$\mathbb{R}$`, ...)
- The package name if I need one (e.g. `\usepackage{amsmath}`)
- SVG

I can create the SVG with the other two pieces of information (although the SVGs I can create are far from optimal), but I currently don't see a better way than manually entering those symbols. This seems like a tremendous waste of time, hearing from the developer of [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/) that he has about 2000 symbols (but he can't give me the database - I don't know why).

So: **How can I get a list of all symbols LaTeX / TeX has?**

(By the way, the site is http://write-math.com - but it still is a very early alpha release and I might truncate the database in the next few days, so please don't waste your time and generate data. The symbol recognition part doesn't exist at the moment.)

Comment: Symbol lists available in plaintext, LaTeX source, or PDF output: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to look up a symbol or identify a math alphabet?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-alphabet)

Comment: @HenriMenke **I don't want** to look up **one** symbol. **I want** to have a processable list of **all** symbols. My question is not a duplicate of the question you've linked.

Comment: @PaulGessler: Thanks, [SYMLIST](ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/info/symbols/comprehensive/SYMLIST) is a nice start. But how do I know if the symbols need other packages / math mode?

Comment: @moose: For that there is the actual [PDF documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) that mentions some of the requirements.

Comment: @moose There's no 'fixed' list, and probably the Detexify database contains what you want. I'd be minded to ask the developer of that tool.

Comment: @moose along with the ruby file, you can find his database at https://github.com/kirel/detexify/blob/master/lib/latex/symbols.yaml This contains the packages required as well as which mode is required.

Comment: For Unicode, see http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode (for use with XeTeX and LuaTeX)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the source for [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) is available on GitHub at https://github.com/kirel/detexify.

The symbols database is provided at [`lib/latex/symbols.yaml`](https://github.com/kirel/detexify/blob/master/lib/latex/symbols.yaml) in a YAML format (sample below) which is easily extensible and satisfies your requirements for information about the required package(s) and mode (text or math).

```yaml
# Table 212: wasysym Biological Symbols
- package: wasysym
  bothmodes:
    - \female 
    - \male
- package: skull
  mathmode:
    - \skull
# Table 254: wasysym General Symbols
- package: wasysym
  textmode:
    - \LEFTarrow
    # <...>
    - \recorder
  bothmodes:
    - \checked #
    # <...>
    - \invdiameter #
```

SVG output can be created by adapting a `rake` task provided in [`lib/rake/symbol_task.rb`](https://github.com/kirel/detexify/blob/master/lib/rake/symbol_task.rb). I present my initial adaptation of this code below. **Disclaimer:** I am a newbie to Ruby, and there are likely better ways to do this since I'm stripping away most of Daniel's code here. Take this as a starting point rather than the standard. `:-)`

```ruby
require 'rake/tasklib'
require 'erb'
require 'latex/symbol'

class SymbolTask < Rake::TaskLib

  TEMPLATE = ERB.new <<-LATEX #open('template.tex.erb').read
    \\documentclass[10pt]{article}
    \\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    <%= @packages %>

    \\pagestyle{empty}
    \\begin{document}

    <%= @command %>

    \\end{document}
  LATEX

  TMP = 'tmp'
  OUT = 'images/latex'

  attr_accessor :name, :tmp, :out

  # initialize sets the name and calls a block to get
  #   the rest of the options
  def initialize(name = :symbols)
      @name = name
      yield self if block_given?
      define
  end

  # define creates the new task(s)
  def define
    #desc "prepare necessary directories"
    #task :prepare do
      directory TMP
      directory OUT
    #end

    all_image_tasks = Latex::Symbol::List.map do |symbol|
      define_single_tex_task symbol
      define_single_dvi_task symbol      
      define_single_image_task symbol
    end

    desc "create svg images from all symbols"
    task :gen_svg => all_image_tasks
  end

  def define_single_image_task symbol
    file "#{File.join(OUT, symbol.filename)}.svg" => [OUT, "#{File.join(TMP, symbol.filename)}.dvi"] do |t|
      # Now convert to image
      puts "Creating image... #{t.name}"
      sh %|dvisvgm -n #{File.join(TMP, symbol.filename)}.dvi #{t.name}| do |ok, res|
        if ! ok
          puts "Major Failure creating image! (status = #{res.exitstatus})"
        end
      end

    end
    "#{File.join(OUT, symbol.filename)}.svg" # need the names
  end

  def define_single_dvi_task symbol
    file "#{File.join(TMP, symbol.filename)}.dvi" => [TMP, "#{File.join(TMP, symbol.filename)}.tex"] do
      puts "Generating dvi for #{symbol}..."
      sh %|latex -interaction=batchmode -output-directory=#{TMP} #{File.join(TMP, symbol.filename)}.tex| do |ok, res|
        if ! ok
          puts "Major Failure creating dvi! (status = #{res.exitstatus})"
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def define_single_tex_task symbol
    file "#{File.join(TMP, symbol.filename)}.tex" => TMP do |t|
      open(t.name, 'w+') do |texfile|
        # setup variables
        @packages = ''
        @packages << "\\usepackage{#{symbol[:package]}}\n" if symbol[:package]
        @packages << "\\usepackage[#{symbol[:fontenc]}]{fontenc}\n" if symbol[:fontenc]
        @command = symbol.mathmode ? "$#{symbol.command}$" : symbol.command
        # write symbol to tempfile
        puts "Generating latex for #{symbol}..."
        texfile.puts TEMPLATE.result(binding)
      end
    end
  end

end
```

I made these modifications on a clone of the detexify repository, but the only files required are [`lib/rake/symbol_task.rb`](https://github.com/kirel/detexify/blob/master/lib/rake/symbol_task.rb), [`lib/latex/symbol.rb`](https://github.com/kirel/detexify/blob/master/lib/latex/symbol.rb), and [`lib/latex/symbols.yaml`](https://github.com/kirel/detexify/blob/master/lib/latex/symbols.yaml).

To build all SVG outputs, execute `rake gen_svg` at a Ruby command prompt. [`dvisvgm`](http://dvisvgm.sourceforge.net/) is required; alternatively, the Ruby code could be modified to use `pdflatex` with [`pdf2svg`](http://www.cityinthesky.co.uk/opensource/pdf2svg/) (untested) or Inkscape (on the command line) to perform the conversion to SVG.